# Give Index of First Item in List that Does Not Contain Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I had for example a list:

`L = ["Archived X", "Pending Y", "Pending Z", "A"]`

How could I get the index of the first item in the list that does not include "Archived" or "Pending", i.e. here '3' (corresponding to "A")?

Comment: `next(i for i, val in enumerate(L) if 'Pending' not in val and 'Archived' not in val)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
import re

L = ["Archived X", "Pending Y", "Pending Z", "A"]
omit_exp = "Archived|Pending"
print([i for i, x in enumerate(L) if len(re.findall(omit_exp, x)) == 0][0])
```

Output: 3

Answer (score 0):

```
L = ["Archived X", "Pending Y", "Pending Z", "A"]
omit = ["Archived", "Pending"]

index=False
for i , x in enumerate(L):
    for om in omit:
        if om not in x:
            index=i
            break
        
print(index)
```

**Result**

```
3
```